# Android Eclipse build error

Tags: android, eclipse

I am an upcoming Android developer. I have many projects I'm working on currently.

I can't build any of my projects because I get this error:

> Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application.

There are no errors in my projects. This happens with all my projects.

Why is this happening?

I really need help. This problem has stopped me for days from getting any work done.

here is a pic of the error
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21264710/zzzz.jpg

Comment: try after clean your project from project->clear

Comment: The error goes away after cleaning, when I hit play again the error comes up.

Comment: can you post code with highlighting error lines

Comment: there should be a tab/view/eclipse thingy with "problems". check out the red stuff there too

Comment: Did you upgrade your AVD or Java version?

Comment: Every time I met this problem without any indication what caused it, turned out to be a problem with the build path. Are you using any libraries and forgot to add them to the build path?

Comment: I attached a pic of the error and build.
There are no error Lines in code.
Yes i upgraded AVD I think.

Comment: Thanks everyone, After deleting my debug keystore it works now.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me too.I solved my problem restarting the Eclipse and showing him once again where my androidsdk was and then creating a new project.You can do this by going into Windows,Preferences,Android and there you can set your androidsdk location.I hope this work for you too.Make sure you have well configured sdk,android tools,platform tools,etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:
"Project Properties" -> "Android Tools" -> "Fix project properties"

Comment: Thanks everyone, After deleting my debug keystore it works now.